# Cantidad de veces que se duplica una frase

Tags: javascript

Este es mi codigo:

```
var frase = prompt("Escríbeme una frase");
var letra = prompt("Escríbeme una letra de esa frase");
var encontrar = frase.indexOf(letra);
```

dicho código pide al usuario que ingrese una frase y una letra de la frase, para así poder averiguar cuantas veces se repite dicha letra, me falta la segunda parte, mi leve idea es que hay que añadir bucles, pero no se como continuar, sería de gran ayuda cualquier aportación.

Comment: Bienvenido Christian! Dale una leida al [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y tambien a [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asi tu pregunta es bien recibida por ende mas usuarios estarian dispuesto a darte una ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer varias cosas, si conviertes la frase en un array (con split) ya puedes hacer lo que quieras con él y es más fácil de manejar.

Puedes usar filter para buscar cuantas veces se encuentra repetido este carácter en el array:

```
let letra = "o";
let frase = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";

let fraseArray = frase.split('');

console.info(fraseArray);

let caracteresRepetidos = fraseArray.filter(letraFrase => letraFrase === letra);
let vecesRepetido = caracteresRepetidos.length;

console.info(vecesRepetido);
```

O también puedes hacer directamente el split (para convertir un string en un array a partir de un carácter) de la frase con el carácter que quieres buscar:

```
let letra = "o";
let frase = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";

let array = frase.split(letra);
console.log(array.length - 1);
```

En ambos casos la longitud del resultado es el número de veces que aparece la letra en la frase.

Comment: Aunque se aprecia el esfuerzo por ayudar al OP, procura no responder a preguntas en donde no se demuestre lo que se ha intentado y/o de baja calidad: lee [answer].